# AngularJS UI-router Change the parent template url from client state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, uiview, angular-ui-router

I'm using `ui-router` for my routing. I would like to know how I can dynamically change the parent templateUrl from a client state (edit state in this case).

```
angular.module('TestModule', ['ui.router'])
.config(['$stateProvider',  '$httpProvider',
    function ($stateProvider,  $httpProvider) {
        'use strict';
        $stateProvider
            .state('index', {
                abstract: true,
                views: {
                    '@': {
                        templateUrl: '/defaultLayout.html',
                        controller: 'layoutController'
                    },
                }]
            })

            .state('login', {
                parent: 'index',
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: '/login.html',
                controller: 'loginController'
            })

            .state('edit', {
                url: '',
                parent: 'index',
              //Change the templateUrl from defaultLayout.html to userLayout.html

            })
            .state('edit.user', {
                url: '/edit/user',
                views: {
                    //code
                }

            });

    }])
.controller('layoutController', function () { })
.controller('layoutFluidController', function () { })
.controller('testCtrl', function () { 

 });
```

Please let me know how this can be achieved. Appreciate your help. Thanks in regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another abstract parent 'index2' with different template url as `.state('index2', { })` and use this as parent for the `edit` state as below,

```
angular.module('TestModule', ['ui.router'])
.config(['$stateProvider',  '$httpProvider',
    function ($stateProvider,  $httpProvider) {
        'use strict';
        $stateProvider
            .state('index', {
                abstract: true,
                views: {
                    '@': {
                        templateUrl: '/defaultLayout.html',
                        controller: 'layoutController'
                    },
                }]
            })
            .state('index2', {
                abstract: true,
                views: {
                    '@': {
                        templateUrl: '/defaultLayout2.html',
                        controller: 'layoutController'
                    },
                }]
            })

            .state('login', {
                parent: 'index',
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: '/login.html',
                controller: 'loginController'
            })

            .state('edit', {
                url: '',
                parent: 'index2',
              //Change the templateUrl from defaultLayout.html to userLayout.html

            })
            .state('edit.user', {
                url: '/edit/user',
                views: {
                    //code
                }

            });

    }])
.controller('layoutController', function () { })
.controller('layoutFluidController', function () { })
.controller('testCtrl', function () { 

 });
```